# How can I shade the area bounded between two 3d curves? How to draw a curtain between them?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

For my tutorial to exemplify the line integral for *z=x+iy* over the unit circle. Therefore, I want to plot the height areas for each part, like curtain between them. So first my main curve is *z(x,y)=x*:

```
th = linspace(0,2*pi,40);
r = linspace(4,4.5,40);
[TH,R] = meshgrid(th,r);
[X,Y] = pol2cart(TH,R);
Z = X;
```

and then I added the xy-plane (*z=0*):

```
mesh(X,Y,Z);
hold on;
% Z threshold value. 
threshold = .0001; % please change this as needed
% Obtain the limits of the axes
yp = get(gca,'Ylim');
xp = get(gca,'Xlim');
% Use the axes x and Y limits to find the co-ordinates for the patch
x1 = [ xp(1) xp(2) xp(2) xp(1)];
y1 = [ yp(1) yp(1) yp(2) yp(2)];
z1 = ones(1,numel(x1))* threshold;  % creates a 1x4 vector representing the Z coordinate values 
p = patch(x1,y1,z1, 'b');
% Set the Face and edge transparency to 0.2 using the following properties
set(p,'facealpha',0.2)
set(p,'edgealpha',0.2)
```

[image: circle and plane]

Now I want to fill the area bounded by the xy-plane and the curve *z(x,y)=x* like a curtain between them. Here is an example of what I mean to get the idea:
[image: example]

Can this be done with [`fill3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill3.html) or [`waterfall`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waterfall.html)?
Even better would be to have the upper and lower curtains to be different colors, to exemplify that they cancel out.

I can also try C++ or Mathematica if you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use `surf`, with a custom `FaceColor` and `FaceAlpha` applied to it. Therefore, you can repeat the `xF` and `yF` coordinates to create the full contour by using `zF` as one bound and then the z-value of the xy-plane (*z=0*) as the other bound.

```
surf(repmat(xF,2,1), repmat(yF,2,1), [zF;ones(size(zF))*0], ...
    'FaceColor','r', 'FaceAlpha', 0.2);
```

`xF`, `yF` and `zF` can be whatever points you like. So you can split the upper part and the lower part easily and create the corresponding coordinates the same way you already did for the circle.

---

*The result can for example look like this:*
[image: result]

There are some other possible improvements in my opinion, which can be seen in the code needed to create the above picture. Here is the complete code for it:

```
radius = 1;                 % radius of the circle projected onto xy-plane
xlim = [-1.25,1.25];        % x-limits
ylim = xlim;                % y-limits
zlim = [-1.25,1.25];        % z-limits

% create new figure, set limits and view
figure; hold on; grid on;
set(gca,'XLim',xlim);
set(gca,'YLim',ylim);
set(gca,'ZLim',zlim);
%view(3);
view([-26,12]);

% draw circle
th = linspace(0,2*pi,40);
r = radius * [0.97,1.03];   % the area in between is filled by surf
[TH,R] = meshgrid(th,r);
[X,Y] = pol2cart(TH,R);
Z = X;
surf(X,Y,Z);                % plot as surface not patch
shading interp;             % remove the edge lines

% draw xy-plane
x1 = [xlim,fliplr(xlim)];
y1 = repelem(ylim,1,2);
z1 = ones(size(x1))*0;
patch(x1,y1,z1, 'k', 'FaceAlpha',0.2, 'EdgeColor','none');

% draw upper curtain
th = linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,40);
[xF,yF] = pol2cart(th,radius);
zF = xF;
surf(repmat(xF,2,1), repmat(yF,2,1), [zF;ones(size(zF))*0], ...
    'FaceColor',[0.85,0.325,0.098], 'FaceAlpha', 0.2);

% draw lower curtain
th = linspace(pi/2,3*pi/2,40);
[xF,yF] = pol2cart(th,radius);
zF = xF;
surf(repmat(xF,2,1), repmat(yF,2,1), [zF;ones(size(zF))*0], ...
    'FaceColor',[0.301,0.745,0.933], 'FaceAlpha', 0.2);
```

---

Instead of using a surface to plot the circle, you could also draw a normal line in 3d-space using `plot3` as shown below. However, it would not be possible (without some hacking) to have multiple colors depending on the height.

```
th = linspace(0,2*pi,40);
[X,Y] = pol2cart(th,radius);
Z = X;
plot3(X,Y,Z, 'r', 'LineWidth',3);
```

It would look like that:

[image: result2]